# How to find the user position on a 2d floor plan if other coordinates (3 or more points) are given?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is it possible to find the position of user if the coordinates of A,B and C are known.D1,D2 and D3 can also be provided.With all these details can we find the user's position(Coordinates/points)?[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Actually I want to know how it is done for coding.Should I paste the codes?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203162/how-to-find-the-user-position-on-a-2d-floor-plan-if-other-coordinates-3-or-more?noredirect=1#comment93295002_53203162

Comment: So your question is: Is it possible to find the user's location, given all the information? Think about it this way: If we only knew the distance from A, it would give us a circle of possible points. When we add the information of the distance from B, we have a second circle. These two circles have exactly $0,1$ or $2$ common points (if A and B are different points). Then we add the last information, the distance from C. How many common points do three non-concentric circles have?

Comment: I understand you have to look for triangulation.Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

If a point X is distance $D_1$ from point $A$, then we know that $X$ is placed on a circle (since the problem is on a 2D plane) with radius $D_1$. This can be formulated as
$$ (x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2 = D_1^2 $$
where $x_i$ and $a_i$ are the $i$:th coordinates of $X$ and $A$.

Doing this for all three measurements gives a system of equations
$$ (x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2 = D_1^2 $$
$$ (x_1-b_1)^2+(x_2-b_2)^2 = D_2^2 $$
$$ (x_1-c_1)^2+(x_2-c_2)^2 = D_3^2 $$

Note that this is overdeterminated. I would recommend solving two of the three equations first. Then three things can happen:

1) There exists exactly one $X$ that satisfies the equations. Verify that it satisfies the third equation as well.

2) No solution exists. This should only happen if the given measurements are incorrect.

3) Two solutions exist. The one that satisfies the third equation is correct.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos                                                                                              1) To get user Latitudes and Longitudes and plot on a 2D map - (Idea dropped because  - For Indoor,  accurate GPS coordinates are not available.)
2) Get device position(x and z values) and add start point in the floor map. When device reaches the start position equate device x and z values to Floors maps x and y values.(Idea dropped because When device is turned left or right the device x and z values varies.)